# Class to calculate performance of a function

Tags: c++

I'm writing a class as follows:

```
struct TimeIt {
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>;
    TimeIt(const std::string& functName) : 
            t1{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()}, 
            functName{functName}  {}

    ~TimeIt() {
        TimePoint t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Exiting from " << functName << "...\n Elapsed: ";
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms" << "\n";
    }
    TimePoint t1;
    std::string functName;
};
```

The whole point of it is measure the time that takes for one function to complete, calling this at the start of it. However, the only value I'm getting is `0ms`. This is obviously wrong, because it takes up to a minute for some of the functions, but I can't see why it's wrong.
I did the same, but at the start and end of the function, creating the `TimePoint` (with auto) and doing a `duration_cast`. Any clue what I'm missing here?

Edit:
I'm going to try to make it reproducible. A little bit of context: I'm working with big matrixes (12000 dimensions) and doing a lot of input output operations.

```
template <typename InputType>
InputMat<InputType> 
readInp(const std::string& filepath = "data.inp", const size_t& reserveSize = 15000) {
    TimeIt("readInp");
    std::ifstream F(filepath);
    assert(F.is_open());
    InputMat<InputType> res;
    res.reserve(reserveSize);
    std::string line;
    while (F >> line) {
        InputType lineBitset{line};
        res.push_back(lineBitset);
    }
    return res;
}
```

This function reads a matrix, and calling `TimeIt` here gives really different results compared when I call it in the wrapper function:

```
void test1() {
    //Testing for 0-1 values
    auto t1 =  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto inpMat = readInp<std::bitset<32>>();
    auto t2 =  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << "\n";

    //More code...
}
```

This outputs:

```
Exiting from readInp...
 Elapsed: 0 milliseconds
4
```

and [data.inp](https://pastebin.com/uz4R1AJr)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.  How are you using it?

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/MWe63Eq84)

Comment: Check the optimiser is not reorganising your code by testing a debug build.

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried with `-O0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOW you have made the problem clear!  By writing this:

```
TimeIt("Reading");
```

you are creating a temporary object, which is immediately deleted.  You need to give this object a name so it lives until the end of the block:

```
TimeIt timer("Reading");
```

Comment: Wow... Too much time coding I think, I didnt see this error while searching for more complicated things

Comment: `struct [[nodiscard]] TimeIt` might help to spot the issue.